# Running into COORS when calling Google Maps API

Tags: cross-domain, webpack, browser-sync, axios

I am using `webpack-dev-middleware` within my React app. When I serve up the google maps assets within the `index.html`, it works great, however, I'd like to fetch those assets within a React component using `axios` and when I do, I get the following error:

```
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I've tried setting these settings within `webpack-dev-middleware`, yet I still get the same issue:

```
webpackDevMiddleware(bundler, {
    ...
    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'X-Requested-With,content-type',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true
    }
  }),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found success for several solutions:

1) I dynamically created a script file pointing to the google maps target and injected it into the DOM

`const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute('src', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=.....');
    document.body.appendChild(script);`

2) After realizing that I was basically rebuilding what `JSONP` is doing, I opted to use the `JSONP` approach, which you can use the `jquery axios` methods or use modules likes `jsonp`.